# Google Compute Engine - Google Cloud Ops Agent Metrics Agent Failed to start

Tags: google-compute-engine

I checked the log using `journalctl -u google-cloud-ops-agent-opentelemetry-collector.service` and found below erorr

***cannot configure Google Cloud metric exporter: stack driver: no project found with application default credentials***

I also have set the credential using `gcloud config set account xx@developer.gserviceaccount.com` with role Editor.

it seems it cannot read the credentials or I'm missing other steps ?

Comment: For Google Cloud Compute Engine a service account is assigned to the instance. The credentials and project are read from the Compute Engine metadata server. The error means you have something configured wrong. Review the Compute Engine `Access Scopes` and the attached service account. Documentation for both items: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts The service account requires the correct IAM role: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/ops-agent/authorization